# A sequence $(f_n)\rightarrow f$ pointwise, where each $f_n$ has at most a finite number of discontinuities, but $f$ is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

I need an example of this, and my thoughts were to try this:

let $\{ r_1, r_2, r_3, ..., \}$ be an enumeration of all the rationals in $[0,1]$

define $g_n(x) = 1$ if $x=r_n$  or $0$ otherwise.

I think this works, the sequence is pointwise convergent to Drichlet's function

Comment: So to clarify, by "integrable" you mean Riemann integrable?

Comment: @carmichael561 the problem statement simply says "integrable". I'm sure Riemann integrable was intended.

Comment: Ok, then it looks like you're on the right track. Though I think you should define $g_n(x)=1$ if $x=r_k$ for $k\leq n$, $g_n(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: I assume that you really mean that $g_n(x) = 1$ if $x$ is one of $r_1, \dotsc, r_n.$

Comment: Or equivalently, you really mean $f_n = \sum_{k=1}^n g_k$

Comment: @IgorRivin I edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you seem to be correct (as far as Riemann integrability is concerned), though your definition isn't completely clear, I understand which functions you refer to.

Each $g_n$ is discontinuous at $r_j, 1\leq j \leq n$, since there exists a sequence of irrationals $i_m$ converging to each $r_j$, but $g_n(i_m) =1  \not \to g_n(r_j) = 0$. However, $g_n$ is continuous at all other points, since given any such point, you can find a neighbourhood of it that avoids $r_j, 1 \leq j \leq n$. So it is locally constant, hence continuous.

$g_n$ is integrable,since you can consider the partition as follows : take points $a_j,b_j$ around each $r_j$, for $1 \leq j \leq n$, such that $[a_j,b_j]$ are disjoint. Now, use these points to create a  partition, and then bring $a_j,b_j$ closer to $r_j$, the upper Riemann sum will then converge to zero, while the lower one will always be zero. That means the Riemann integral is zero.

However, the pointwise limit $g$, which is the characteristic function of rationals in $[0,1]$, *isn't* Riemann integrable, for this reason: suppose you take a partition of $[0,1]$. The upper Riemann sums involve supremums to be taken over each interval of the partition, while the lower Riemann sums involve infimums to be taken over the interval. However, over *every interval*, $g$ has supremum $1$ and infimum $0$. Hence, regardless of which partition you take, the upper Riemann sum will always be $1$ and the lower Riemann sum will be $0$, so the Riemann integral can't exist.

Comment: There's no reason to bring measure theory into this.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the answer so that I can omit Lebesgue integrability.